# set multiple='false' in a form in a many to many relation symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a many-to-many relationship between two entities A and B.

So when adding a form, in order to add `entityA` to `entityB`, I am doing the following:

```
$builder          
    ->add('entityAs', 'entity', array(
      'class'    => 'xxxBundle:EntityA',
      'property' => 'name',
      'multiple' => true,
    ));}
```

And everything is alright.

But depending on the field type of entityA, I want to sometimes set 'multiple' to false, so I'm doing the following :

```
if($type=='a'){
    $builder          
        ->add('entityAs', 'entity', array(
          'class'    => 'xxxBundle:entityA',
          'property' => 'name',
          'multiple' => true,
        ));}

else {
    $builder          
        ->add('entityAs', 'entity', array(
          'class'    => 'xxxBundle:entityA',
          'property' => 'name',
          'multiple' => false,

        ));
}
```

This gives me the following error:

```
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be an array, object given, called in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\orm\lib\Doctrine\ORM\UnitOfWork.php on line 519 and defined in C:\wamp\www\Symfony\vendor\doctrine\common\lib\Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection.php line 48
```

Can anybody help me?

Comment: are you sure that error is raised here?

Comment: yes actually @DonCallisto

Comment: I bet no. I bet that error is into your entities: you expect to have an ArrayCollection, but you have a single entity (object) and this will cause you a problem.

Comment: but it's working when multiple=true ? @DonCallisto I examined my entities and cannot find any anomality

Comment: Why do you want multiple to be false ?

Comment: @user2269869: is perfectly clear that with multiple=true it works, this is because you will pass an ArrayCollection (as expected) and not a single entity

Comment: @PéCé , as I mentionned it's dependinng on the value of type that I want to set multiple to false. whenever type<>a I want the user to select only one value for entityA. otherwise he may choose more than one

Comment: @DonCallisto how to make then a single value pass as an arrayCollection ?

Comment: @user2269869: if you use symfony2 form facility, I suppose that you have to build all things in the proper way and not to "hack" such things

Comment: can you explain me better the meaning of form facility? @DonCallisto

Comment: I mean that if you use entities, form types and so on, i suppose that you haven't to do anything, apart "configure" them in proper way. I tell you that because I'm using symfony2 since about 1 year and I've never struggle with this problem because all mechanism was always auto (except some cases, where I have to write custom query for populate dropdown list)

Comment: You can deal with validation contraint on Collection : http://symfony.com/doc/2.1/reference/constraints/Count.html

Comment: how could that help me? @PéCé

Comment: forget that, i was wrong !

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In EntityA, you have something like this, right?

```
public function setEntitiesB($data)
{
    $this->entitiesB = $data ;
}
```

Now because you can also receive single value instead of array of values, you need something like this:

```
public function setEntitiesB($data)
{
    if ( is_array($data) ) {
        $this->entitiesB = $data ;
    } else {
        $this->entitiesB->clear() ;
        $this->entitiesB->add($data) ;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i would check the entityA value in the controller and depending on it create different forms.

in controller:

```
if ($entityA->getType() == 'a') { 
    $form = new FormB(); // form with multiple true
} else {
    $form = new FormA(); // form with multiple false
}
```

Comment: I still have the same error message when trying this. @Laurynas

Comment: this can not be true. FormA and FormB are two independent forms which should be processed differently, so no errors could pop up.