# many to many relation in a form view symfony 2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a many to many relation between two entities.

I display then a form to add entityA to entityB.
Isn't possible to add a customized form (I mean in the twig view) in order to enable the user sometimes to select one value and sometimes more than one?

when I want the user to select more than one value, I use this

```
<select multiple>
{% for entity in entitys %}
<option> 
{{entity.id}}

 </option>
{%endfor%}
</select>
```

otherwise this

```
 <select >
    {% for entity in entitys %}
    <option> 
    {{entity.id}}

     </option>
    {%endfor%}
    </select>
```

but now the problem is how to submit the form. the

```
<button  type="submit"  class="btn btn-info"    value="NEXT STEP " />
```

Here is the whole form

```
<form method="post">
  <select >
    {% for entity in entitys %}
    <option> 
    {{entity.id}}

     </option>
    {%endfor%}
    </select>

<input  type="submit"     /> 

</form>
```

no longer submit the form. any ideas plz??

here is my entire twig view

```
  <h2> STEP {{step}} </h2>
  <form method="post">
<select >
{% for entity in entitys %}
<option value="{{entity.id}}"> 
{{entity.id}}

 </option>
{%endfor%}
</select>

<input  type="submit"  class="btn btn-info"     /> 

</form>
  <br>
  <br>
```

Comment: can you show us the `form` tag please ? Also How do you know if you want a multiple select or not ?

Comment: Does your problem is that the form is not well renderer or/and it does nothing on submit ?

Comment: @0x1gene I know it through a value in the controller. This is not diffucult. My problem is it does nothing on submit. I'll join my form

Comment: Does the form's action attribute well set in your view ?

Comment: yes it's well displayed and when I click the button it seems like it's submitting but when I check the database I can not find anything @0x1gene

Comment: Can you include the html content that is render by twig, I mean the html's source code of your entire form please ?

Comment: I joined my twig view @0x1gene

Comment: from your twig it seems that your form doesn't have any action, the browser doesn't know where to send data (see my edited answer)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/29974/discussion-between-user2269869-and-0x1gene)

Comment: even when adding the path responsible for submission, I get nothing in the database

Answer (score 2):

In your formbuilder you can add some options like in my exemple:

The aim is to map your field to an entity (to setup the list). Don't forget to add a method _tostring to your mapped entity to make symfony able to represent your entity as a text in your select.

### In your formType

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilder $builder, array $options) {
        $id = $this->id;

        $builder->add(
            'addressees',
            'entity',
            array(
                        'class' => 'Pref27\MailBundle\Entity\Addressee',
                        'property' => 'name',
                        'multiple' => true,
                    'expanded' => false,
                        'required' => true,
                        'label' => 'mail.add.theme';
                }
            )
        );
    }
```

### In your formControler

```
$editForm = $this->createForm(new FormType(), $entity);
return array(
            'form'   => $editForm->createView()
        );
```

### In your view

```
<form action="{{ path('theControllerActionWitchIsResponsibeOfRecordingIntoDatabase' }}" method="post" {{ form_enctype(edit_form) }}>
        {{ form_widget(edit_form) }}
        <p>
            <button type="submit">Next step</button>
        </p>
</form>
```

The type of field rendered will depend on setting of multiple and expended

```
select tag                                  expanded=false  multiple=false
select tag (with multiple attribute)        expanded=false  multiple=true
radio buttons                               expanded=true   multiple=false
checkboxes                                  expanded=true   multiple=true
```

you can find more information about entity type in form here : http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html

### EDIT:

From your twig view form's action is missing
try to add

```
<form method="post" action="{{ path("theRouteOfYourControllerWitchRecordTheData")}}">
```

don't forget to add `{{form_rest(form) }}` To tell twig to add the CSRF token

and don't forget to add value in your select's option

```
<select multiple>
  {% for entity in entitys %}
       <option value="{{entity.id}}">{{entity.name}}</option>
  {%endfor%}
</select>
```

Comment: I already tried this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539244/set-multiple-false-in-a-form-in-a-many-to-many-relation-symfony2?noredirect=1#comment23781646_16539244 but with no result