# change type of relation between two entities symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I wanted to ask if we can modify the type of a relation between two entities depending on a specific value.
I mean if $type==a the relation is many to many otherwise it must be  many t one.
is that possible???
any ideas???

Comment: The answer to your specific question is no but if you provide some context about what you're trying to do people can help suggest a suitable approach.

Comment: I want the following http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539244/set-multiple-false-in-a-form-in-a-many-to-many-relation-symfony2?noredirect=1#comment23781646_16539244 and this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16559927/many-to-many-relation-in-a-form-view-symfony-2/16560048?noredirect=1#16560048

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you can do is instantiate an object on a certain condition: so, if condition A is true, you can instantiate one. If B, other.

Obviously, you can define a different cardinality for `objectA` and `objectB`.

Remember that cardinality is defined statically and is used to create (or use) DB schema