# Overriding multiple select in symfony 2 formbuilder

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

So, I have a formbuilder action which has, in part, this:

```
->add('apples_group', 'entity', 
    array(
        'class' => 'ThingMainBundle:ApplesGroup', 
        'multiple' => true,
        'expanded' => true,
        'property' => 'applesName'
    )
)
```

This currently outputs as a multi-select box in this code:

```
{{ form_widget(form.apples_group, { "attr": {"class": "fields-list" } }) }}
```

Sometimes - in a different View - this needs not to be multiple, and should be a dropdown box instead. Is there a way to specify to the widget that the attribute multiple should be false when you render this widget?

(Validation of if this allowed to be multiple in this circumstance is already on the back end)

Comment: I don't really know what will switch from one way to the other in your case but you might find the [Form Events](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/dynamic_form_modification.html) really useful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is better to create

```
// YourFormType.php
public function __construct(Apple $apple)
{
    $this->apple = $apple;
}
```

and

```
->add('apples_group', 'entity', 
    array(
        'class' => 'ThingMainBundle:ApplesGroup', 
        'multiple' => $this->apple->isMultiple() ,  // you set it in admin, right?
        'expanded' => true,
        'property' => 'applesName'
    )
)
```

controller:

```
$entity = new Apple() ;
$form = $this->createForm( new YourFormType($entity), $entity) ;
```

Comment: This didn't work for me, because I got the data validation error when it wasn't multiple (because it was attempting to save it as a value instead of as a reference to another table)

Comment: That's different problem, I answered it on: http://stackoverflow.com/a/16564513/377192

Answer (score 0):

So it looks like the actual answer is to wait until https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/6602 lands.