# Many to Many Relationship Setter

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, mapping, setter

I have a Many to Many relationship between my Entities: `PurchaseOrder` and `Supplier`. When I want do add a `Supplier` to an order in my Symfony project, I always get this error message:

> Property "suppliers" is not public in class
>   "Acme\AppBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder". Maybe you should create the
>   method "setSuppliers()"?

When I make a `setSuppliers()` function by myself in the `PurchaseOrder` Entity:

```
public function setSuppliers(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Supplier $suppliers )
{
    $this->suppliers = $suppliers;

    return $this;
}
```

I get this error message:

> Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to
>   Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection::__construct() must be of
>   the type array, object given, called in
>   /var/www/symfony/vendor/doctrine/orm/lib/Doctrine/ORM/UnitOfWork.php
>   on line 519 and defined in
>   /var/www/symfony/vendor/doctrine/collections/lib/Doctrine/Common/Collections/ArrayCollection.php
>   line 47

Any ideas?

```
/**
 * @Route("order/{id}/supplieradd", name="order_supplieradd")
 * @Secure(roles="ROLE_ADMIN")
 */
public function newSupplierAction(Request $request, $id)
{
    $purchaseOrder = $this->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('AcmeAppBundle:PurchaseOrder')
    ->find($id);

    if (!$purchaseOrder) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
                'No order found for id '.$id
        );
    }

    $form = $this->createForm(new AddSupplierType(), $purchaseOrder);

    // process the form on POST
    if ($request->isMethod('POST')) {
        $form->bind($request);
        if ($form->isValid()) {             

            $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

            $em->persist($purchaseOrder);
            $em->flush();

            return new Response('Added Supplier to Order with ID '.$articleOrder->getId());
        }
    }

    return $this->render('AcmeAppBundle:BasicData:newSupplier.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView(),
            'id' => $id,
    ));
}
```

And my `AddSupplierType.php`

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
{
    $builder->add('suppliers', 'entity', array(
         'class' => 'AcmeAppBundle:Supplier',
         'property' => 'name',
    ));
}
```

Some parts of the `PurchaseOrder` and `Supplier` entities:

```
 class PurchaseOrder{
  ...
         /**
         * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Supplier", mappedBy="purchaseOrders")     
         */
    private $suppliers;

    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->suppliers = new ArrayCollection();
    }

/**
 * Add suppliers
 *
 * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Supplier $suppliers
 * @return PurchaseOrder
 */
public function addSupplier(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Supplier $suppliers)
{
    $this->suppliers[] = $suppliers;

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove suppliers
 *
 * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Supplier $suppliers
 */
public function removeSupplier(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Supplier $suppliers)
{
    $this->suppliers->removeElement($suppliers);
}

/**
 * Get suppliers
 *
 * @return \Doctrine\Common\Collections\Collection 
 */
public function getSuppliers()
{
    return $this->suppliers;
}
}

class Supplier{
    ...

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="PurchaseOrder", inversedBy="suppliers")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="suppliers_purchaseOrders")
     */
    private $purchaseOrders;
}
```

New add remove set methods:

```
 /**
     * Add supplier
     *
     * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Supplier $supplier
     * @return PurchaseOrder
     */
public function addSupplier(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Supplier $supplier)
{
    $this->suppliers->add($supplier);

    return $this;
}

/**
 * Remove supplier
 *
 * @param \Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Supplier $supplier
 */
public function removeSupplier(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Supplier $supplier)
{
    $this->suppliers->removeElement($supplier);
}

public function setSuppliers($supplier)
{
     if ( is_array($supplier) ) {
        $this->suppliers = $supplier ;
    } else {
        $this->suppliers->clear() ;
        $this->suppliers->add($supplier) ;
    }
}
```

Comment: `When I want do add a Supplier to an order in my Symfony project` Can you show us the code doing this?

Comment: Sure, i added my first post

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Problems:

1. Grammatically incorrect method name and its argument:

   ```
   public function addSupplier(\Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Supplier $suppliers)
   ```

   method says addSupplier (singular) but you are accepting supplierS (plural)
2. You need refactoring on this method to be:

   ```
   public function addSupplier(Supplier $supplier)
   {
       $this->suppliers->add($supplier) ;
   }
   ```

   also:

   ```
   public function removeSupplier(Supplier $supplier)
   {
       $this->suppliers->removeElement($supplier) ;
   }
   ```

   Getter and setter method will work if you do it like my answer on: [set multiple='false' in a form in a many to many relation symfony2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539244/set-multiple-false-in-a-form-in-a-many-to-many-relation-symfony2/16564513?noredirect=1#comment23800026_16564513)

Symfony will find add...() and remove...() methods by itself. So if relation is "suppliers", it will find addSupplier. Or if relation is "categories", it will find addCategory() and removeCategory().

Comment: Very complete answer, I also would suggest the use of 'doctrine:generate:entities' console command (or equivalent), to avoid this kind of mistakes.

Comment: thanks a lot for your answer, I refactored the methods to singular and changed my setter. But when i want to add a supplier on my page I only see a blank page with no error messages. I put the new add/remove and set method on the bottom of my first post.

Comment: You still do $suppliers and not $supplier (singluar) argument. You also didn't create setSuppliers($data) like my answer on other topic. And at what point you get blank page? On first load or after form submission? For quicker testing, get rid of $id parameter in controller action and use some known id from database.

Comment: I see you are editing your post at this moment: do as I said for setSuppliers($data), -do not- typehint it.

Comment: yes sorry, I was to slow ;) . I changed the Supplier $supplier in the setSupplier method to only $supplier. But there is still the blank page. And I must clear my browser cache (app_dev.php) before I can return to my supplieradd Route or any other Route.

Comment: When do you get blank page? On first load or after you submit it? Also; remove the $id from your controller (both in argument and checking it) and use known id from database (eg: 5)

Comment: After my submit. I removed the $id and used the ID for my first Supplier (eg: 1) , but still blank page

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30210/discussion-between-zeljko-and-yoda)

Comment: It works now, the doctrine associations were wrong. purchaseOrder is the inversed Side and Supplier is the owning Side. thanks

Answer (score -1):

Shouldn't your `setSupliers` method take an `ArrayCollection` as the first argument?

```
public function setSuppliers(ArrayCollection $suppliers )
{
    $this->suppliers = $suppliers;

    return $this;
}
```

As you initalized it as `ArrayCollection` in your constructor. With your `setSuppliers` method
you will convert your `ArrayCollection` to one single `Supplier` Object.

Your form will return one single selected `Suplier` Object. If this is realy what you want, why don't you use a OnyToMany realtionship? 
Otherwise you could add the [multiple](http://symfony.com/doc/2.2/reference/forms/types/entity.html#multiple) option to your form field. Then multiple Suplier objects can be returned as array.

Comment: When i use ArrayCollection I get almost the same Error: 
Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Acme\AppBundle\Entity\PurchaseOrder::setSuppliers() must be an instance of Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection, instance of Acme\AppBundle\Entity\Supplier given, called in /var/www/symfony/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/PropertyAccess/PropertyAccessor.php on line 350 and defined in /var/www/symfony/src/Acme/AppBundle/Entity/PurchaseOrder.php line 508

Comment: And when i use 'multiple' => true in my AddSupplierType , I get linked to an blank site and nothing happens.

I need a Many To Many Relation, because my orders can have multiple Suppliers and I want to add a Supplier with this Form to the an order