# Symfony2 - Collection of Forms - Update -ManytoMany-Relation

Tags: php, symfony

I'm very new to Symfony2 and now I have a problem with a collection of forms. I have two Entities. The Entity User and the Entity Role.

Entity User

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=25, unique=true)
 */
private $username;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=32)
 */
private $salt;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=250)
 */
private $password;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(type="string", length=60, unique=true)
 */
private $email;



/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="is_active", type="boolean")
 */
private $isActive;

 /**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
 *
 */
private $roles;
```

Entity Role

```
/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="id", type="integer")
 * @ORM\Id()
 * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
 */
private $id;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="name", type="string", length=30)
 */
private $name;

/**
 * @ORM\Column(name="role", type="string", length=20, unique=true)
 */
private $role;

/**
 * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
 * @ORM\JoinTable(name="user_role",
 *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
 *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
 *      )
 */
private $users;

public function __construct()
{
    $this->users = new ArrayCollection();
}
```

Controller

```
public function editUserAction($id, Request $request)
{
    $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
    $user = $em->getRepository('PsoLogBundle:User')->find($id);
    $form =  $this->createForm(new NewUserType(),$user);
    $form->handleRequest($request);
    if (!$user) {
        throw $this->createNotFoundException(
            'No news found for id ' . $id
        );
    }


    if ($form->isValid()) {
        $em->flush();
    $this->get('session')->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'User updated successfully');
    }

    $build['form'] = $form->createView();

    return $this->render('PsoLogBundle:Security:editUser.html.twig', $build);

}
```

Now I have a collection of Forms with the user and the Role, that is saved in DB for the User. When I make a change on the Role I got the error "An exception occurred while executing 'UPDATE pso_role SET role = ? WHERE id = ?' with params ["ROLE_ADMIN", 2]"

The Problem is that Symfony wants to make the change on the Table for the Entity Role. In fact it should be an new entry in the table for the relationship User - Role. I searched in Google and here in stackoverflow but I can't find what i have to change.

I think the problem is perhaps the formbuilder

```
$builder ->add('username','text', array('label' => 'Username')) 
     ->add('email','email', array('label' => 'Email')) 
     ->add('isActive','text', array('label' => 'User aktiv')) 
     ->add('Roles', 'collection', array('type' => new RoleType())) 
     ->add('Submit', 'submit', array( 'attr'=> array ( 'formnovalidate' => 'formnovalidate' )));
```

could it be, that the line add('Roles', 'collection', array('type' => new RoleType())) defines the entity, which should be updated? Can i change this

If I don't use it with a collection of forms, but only with a single form, everything works fine, because then only one entity is affected. I would be glad, if somebody can give me a hint.

Now I tried it in the Formbuilder with 
    ->add('roles', 'entity', array('class' => 'PsoLogBundle:Role','property' => 'role'))

Then I get the error "Neither the property "roles" nor one of the methods "setRoles()", "__set()" or "__call()" exist and have public access in class "Pso\LogBundle\Entity\User". "

I tried to insert in Entity User the setter

```
public function setRoles( ArrayCollection $roles)
{
$this->roles = $roles;
return $this;
}
```

Then I get the error ContextErrorException: Catchable Fatal Error: Argument 1 passed to Pso\LogBundle\Entity\User::setRoles() must be an instance of Pso\LogBundle\Entity\ArrayCollection, instance of Pso\LogBundle\Entity\Role given, called in C:\xampp\htdocs\pso\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\PropertyAccess\PropertyAccessor.php on line 347 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\pso\src\Pso\LogBundle\Entity\User.php line 99

I tried to solve the problem with

```
      'multiple' => false,
```

like I found in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539244/set-multiple-false-in-a-form-in-a-many-to-many-relation-symfony2/16564513?noredirect=1#comment23800026_16564513)

But that doesn't change the situation.

I added in the user.php a setter for the role

```
// Important
public function setRoles($roles)
{
    foreach($roles as $p)
    {
        $po = new user_role();

        $po->setUser($this);
        $po->setRoles($p);

        $this->addPo($po);
    }

}
```

When I do this and generate setters and getters new, I get no error, when I change the role for a user, but in DB the entry doesn't change.

After many hours searching, I got it to work now. The setter before is right. Additionally I changed the formbuilder like

```
->add('roles', 'entity', array('class' => 'PsoLogBundle:Role','property' => 'role','multiple' => true,))
```

Now the role changes correctly, when I submit the form. Thanks for evereybody answering, so that I got the right direction. I hope, everything works fine now.

Greetings
Micha

Comment: I think the problem is perhaps the formbuilder   [code] $builder
      ->add('username','text', array('label' => 'Username'))
   ->add('email','email', array('label' => 'Email'))
   ->add('isActive','text', array('label' => 'User aktiv'))
   ->add('Roles', 'collection', array('type' => new RoleType()))
   ->add('Submit', 'submit', array(
    'attr'=> array (
     'formnovalidate' => 'formnovalidate'
    )
   ));[/code] could it be, that the line add('Roles', 'collection', array('type' => new RoleType())) defines the entity, which should be updated? Can i change this

Comment: May you please add that code in your OP?

Comment: Please share mapping fields of both entities. you need to define name of 3rd table as well. refer this > link
> http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/annotations-reference.html#annref-manytomany

Comment: Thanks for your hint. When I created the Entities I did it lihttp://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database Now I definded the mapping fields like the next answer from herr, but the situation is the same. I added the code in my OP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should have in your user entity :

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="Role", inversedBy="users")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="role_assigned_to_user",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="role_id", referencedColumnName="id")}
     *      )
     */
    private $roles;
```

In your role entity:

```
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="User", mappedBy="roles")
     */
    private $users;
```

in your role constructor:

```
    public function __construct() {
       $this->users = new \Doctrine\Common\Collections\ArrayCollection();
    }
```

Instead of collection it will multi select:

```
->add('roles', 'entity', array(
            'class' => 'YourBundle:Role',
            'property' => 'name',
        ))
```

Comment: Thanks for your hint. The situation doesn't change. When I created the Entities  I did it like http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/security/entity_provider.html#managing-roles-in-the-database. Was this the correct way? Or is your way of definition the correct or better way?